# Pulling wiki to html using php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, dokuwiki

I would like to change wiki syntax to html using these techniques mentioned here.

http://www.ladyada.net/library/software/wiki.html

Here is the source code of my php page which seems to work fine. You may try yourself like this:

http://temelelektronik.net/wiki/show.php?id=test

```
<?
if(!defined('DOKU_INC')) define('DOKU_INC',realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/');
require_once(DOKU_INC.'inc/init.php');
require_once(DOKU_INC.'inc/common.php');
require_once(DOKU_INC.'inc/events.php');
require_once(DOKU_INC.'inc/pageutils.php');
require_once(DOKU_INC.'inc/html.php');
require_once(DOKU_INC.'inc/auth.php');
require_once(DOKU_INC.'inc/actions.php');

//import variables
$QUERY = trim($_REQUEST['id']);
$ID = getID();

$REV = $_REQUEST['rev'];
$HIGH = $_REQUEST['s'];
if(empty($HIGH)) $HIGH = getGoogleQuery();

//sanitize revision
$REV = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$REV);

$html = p_wiki_xhtml($ID,$REV,true);
$html = addslashes($html);
$html = ereg_replace("\n", '\n'."\\\n", $html);
$html = str_replace("</a>", "</a> ", $html);

echo ('var zoomy = "'.$html.'";');
echo ("document.write(zoomy);");

$url = "http://www.temelelektronik.net/wiki/" . str_replace(':', '/', $_REQUEST['id']);
$footer = '<hr /><br /><em>This page was autogenerated from
<a href=\"'.$url.'\" target=\"_blank\">' . $url . '</a> <br />Please edit the wiki to contribute any updates or corrections.</em>';

$footer = '"' . $footer . '"';
echo ('document.write('. $footer . ')');
?>
```

But when I add this Javascript code to a blank html page I see nothing. Here is the HTML file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="Javascript" src="/show.php?id=test"></script>
</head>
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

As you'd see it shows nothing.

http://temelelektronik.net/wiki/test.html

How can I solve this issue? Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Because you supplied the wrong URL?

```
http://temelelektronik.net/wiki/show.php?id=test
```

vs.

```
<script language="Javascript" src="/show.php?id=test"></script>
```

Apparently it should be /wiki/show.php?id=test

Comment: I don't think so but apparently the only problem was naming pages without .html extension. Finally it works :) [Thanks](http://temelelektronik.net/thanks.html)

Comment: No the problem was not related to naming wiki pages without .html extension. After putting the .html files to the root directory the problem resolved. (Before I used to upload files to the /wiki directory instead of root directory) Anyway thanks.